# Creating building shadows in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, shadow, building-heights

Can anyone think of a simple way to create a polygon to represent building shadows?

I have a shapefile with height information for the buildings and I want to create a simple plan looking like the image below:

[image: dropped shadows]

I don't want it to be accurate based on the terrain etc or really specific of the sun, but just a way to demonstrate the height of the building with a shadow that is connected to the building.

Comment: You need can use the 2.5 D render where you use your height column as a data defined input

Comment: here is a short video on the 2.5D Render as mentioned by @kartoza-geek https://vimeo.com/149742884

Comment: Yes, I'll try to get an answer written up using a Geometry Generator that uses the translate(geom,dx,dy) function. It should be able to get the delta x and delta y values from your height field and maybe even using a scale() function. Currently away from desk so will try to get it up in a bit here if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Answer (score 7):

Use `Translate`, in the toolbox:

[image: Translate]

here I set dx and dy both to `.71*Height` to simulate a 45° sun incidence, but you can use whatever combination you prefer.

This creates a new layer, which you have to move under your original one, and set to a dark shade. Optionally, for a smoother rendering, set a slight blur with the `Draw effect`:

[image: add-a-blur]

Comment: Thant's great! thank you!
Any ideas on how to connect the corner of the shadows to the corner of the buildings?

Comment: Where did the `.71` come from and how is this used to simulate the sun angle?

Comment: `.71` is an approximation of `cos(45°)` , where 45° is the incidence angle of the sun light that I wanted to simulate. At noon the sun may be for example 70° (depending on day of the year and your latitude), so you could use `cos(70°) = 0.34` and shadows will be correspondingly shorter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use also the Draw effects and select Drop Shadow option. Using this option does not require to create a new file with modified geometry. Drop Shadow option gives you the ability to change the Blur and the direction of shadow freely and easily without the need to create a new file each time.

- Go the buildings polygon's `Layer properties -> Symbology -> select
  Simple fill -> Draw Effects`

[image]

- Click on the Yellow star
- Select the Drop shadow option and select it to see its options

[image]

Here is a sample building before and after using Draw effects:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: This is a good and fast approach, however it does not take into account the actual building height, i.e. all shadows are offset by the same distance. For a quick visual effect however it is a good compromise. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but in case anyone is looking for how to set this up using the 2.5 D symbology mentioned in the comments here it is:

[image: 25D Setup]

The key is to generate a negative height. In this case I am multiplying my stories field  by -10. Make sure to turn off shade walls based on aspect and shadow.